# How do you pass body data with an Amplify REST request?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, aws-amplify

I'm using the [AWS amplify REST API](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/fetch/q/platform/js) to make a get request to my lambda function in React Native. The API/Lambda function was generated by the Amplify CLI.

```
  const getData = async (loca) => {
    const apiName = "api1232231321";
    const path = "/mendpoint";
    const myInit = {
      body: {
        name: "bob",
      },
      queryStringParameters: {
        location: JSON.stringify(loca),
      },
    };

    return API.get(apiName, path, myInit);
  };
```

Unless I remove the body from this request, it just returns `Error: Network Error` with no other details. I seem to be able to get the `queryStringParameters` just fine though if I remove the body object.

If I do this, the request goes through fine without errors

```
const myInit = JSON.stringify({
  body: {
    name: "bob",
  },
});
```

But the `body` in the `event` (event.body) in lambda is always null. Same result if change `body` to `data` as well. My second thought was that perhaps I can only pass body data with a `POST` request however the docs seem to show that you can use a `GET` request [since it documents how to access said body data](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/fetch/q/platform/js#accessing-query-parameters--body-in-lambda-proxy-function)...

**Lambda function**

```
exports.handler = async(event) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(event),
  };
  return response;
};
```

How do I correctly pass body data?

Answer (score 5):

The Amplify SDK won't send a body on a `API.get()` call. You're first example looks fine but you'll need to use `API.post()` (or put) instead.

```js
  const getData = async (loca) => {
    const apiName = "api1232231321";
    const path = "/mendpoint";
    const myInit = {
      body: {
        name: "bob",
      },
      queryStringParameters: {
        location: JSON.stringify(loca),
      },
    };

    return API.post(apiName, path, myInit);
  };
```

Comment: do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @giladrv - No reference that I can find. Just experience with attempting to use API.get() and having it fail. For all I know they may have changed that behavior by now.

Comment: here https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/update/q/platform/js/